# Testcafe Docker - Error: TypeScript compilation failed.Cannot find name 'require'

Tags: typescript, docker, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I am getting below error when I try to run type script from latest testcafe docker image.

The same script was working fine with the older version docker pull testcafe/testcafe:1.4.3.

Create ts file and add below code

var config = require('./loginDetails.json');
and try to run it from testcafe docker.

Command used:

docker run -v /var/jenkins/workspace/:/tests -i testcafe/testcafe 'chromium --no-sandbox' '/tests/*.ts' -e -u --selector-timeout 10000 --assertion-timeout 10000 -S -s /tests -r spec,xunit:/tests/res.xml,json:/tests/res.json -T '1681'

Error: TypeScript compilation failed.
/tests/commonFunctions.ts (2, 14): Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`.
/tests/commonFunctions.ts (52, 25): Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`.
/tests/commonFunctions.ts (53, 13): Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`.
/tests/commonFunctions.ts (55, 28): Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`.
/tests/commonFunctions.ts (89, 22): Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`.
/tests/login.ts (3, 14): Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`.

```
at Function._reportErrors (/usr/lib/node_modules/testcafe/src/compiler/test-file/formats/typescript/compiler.ts:79:15)
at TypeScriptTestFileCompiler._compileFilesToCache (/usr/lib/node_modules/testcafe/src/compiler/test-file/formats/typescript/compiler.ts:101:40)
at TypeScriptTestFileCompiler._precompileCode (/usr/lib/node_modules/testcafe/src/compiler/test-file/formats/typescript/compiler.ts:129:18)
at TypeScriptTestFileCompiler._compileCodeForTestFiles (/usr/lib/node_modules/testcafe/src/compiler/test-file/api-based.js:111:29)
at tsConfig.init.then (/usr/lib/node_modules/testcafe/src/compiler/test-file/formats/typescript/compiler.ts:85:30)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is already described in this [issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4437) in the TestCafe repository. Track it to be notified once it's updated.

**UPDATE: We have resolved this issue.**